# Angular Kendo-UI Multiple Grids AutoFitColumns

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm trying to use the autoFitColumns() for a page with two grids, but it only seems to work for the first grid. I've used two different id's for each grid, and it still doesn't work. Does anyone have an idea how to get them both to resize?

```
<kendo-grid #grid [kendoGridBinding]="salesData"
                  kendoGridSelectBy="id"
                  [sortable]="true"
                  [reorderable]="true"
                  [resizable]="true"
                  [rowClass]="rowCallback"
                  [ngStyle]="gridHeight"
                  [columnMenu]="false"> </kendo-grid>
<kendo-grid #grid2 [kendoGridBinding]="salesDataMisc"
              [sortable]="true"
              [reorderable]="true"
              [resizeable]="true"
              [rowClass]="rowCallback"
              [height]="300"
              [columnMenu]="false"> </kendo-grid>
```

In my .ts file, I have two separate calls for autoFitColumns() (for each grid), which are called during the ngOnInit()

```
fitColumns(): void {
this.ngZone.onStable.asObservable().pipe(take(15)).subscribe(() => {
  this.grid.autoFitColumns();      
});
 }
fitMiscColumns(): void {
this.ngZone.onStable.asObservable().pipe(take(15)).subscribe(() => {
  this.grid2.autoFitColumns();
});
```